# Blender 2.91 Eevee Viewport Render different from Viewport View?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

First off, let me say this is not a matter of viewport view being different from the final F12 camera render, but rather the difference I get between the viewport view and the render I get from "viewport render image".

Why am I not getting the viewport render image exactly the same as the one I have on my "combined" eevee viewport?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show images that illustrate the problem. It is hard to guess what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it.

Comment: Are you using any clamping or the bloom?

Comment: No, but if I remove the bloom the difference in color and brightness remains the same. I feel it has to do with the filmic look not being properly displayed in the viewport render.